# uninitialized constant Article::PictureUploader (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm writing a demo to practice the gem of "carrierwave", and it worked all well in **development ENV**, but failed when I deployed to **Heroku**.

When I : *heroku run rails s*, get this error:

> /app/app/models/article.rb:9:in `': uninitialized constant Article::PictureUploader (NameError)

There's my codes:
app/models/article.rb

```
  class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :likes
    validates :title, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}
    validates :content, length: {minimum: 10}
    self.per_page = 10
    attr_accessor :floor_number
    mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
    validate :picture_size
```

uploaders/picture_uploader.rb

```
  class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

    include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

    process resize_to_limit: [600, 600]

    storage :qiniu

    def store_dir
      "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
    end

   def extension_white_list
     %w{jpg gif png jpeg}
   end
 end
```

db/schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150529021048) do

  create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "content"
    t.string   "label"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string   "picture"
  end

  add_index "articles", ["user_id"], name: "index_articles_on_user_id"

  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "article_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "comments", ["article_id"], name:       "index_comments_on_article_id"
  add_index "comments", ["user_id"], name: "index_comments_on_user_id"

  create_table "likes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "likes_num"
    t.integer  "article_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "likes", ["article_id"], name: "index_likes_on_article_id"

  create_table "messages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "messages", ["user_id"], name: "index_messages_on_user_id"

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "name"
    t.boolean  "admin"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name:  "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

Error:

> yesijiedeMacBook-Pro:blog killernova$ heroku run rails c
>   Running `rails c` attached to terminal... up, run.2077
>   /app/app/models/article.rb:9:in `<class:Article>': uninitialized constant Article::PictureUploader (NameError)
>       from /app/app/models/article.rb:1:in`'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:472:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in`each'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `block in eager_load!'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in`each'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `eager_load!'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in`eager_load!'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in`block in '
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`run'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in`block in tsort_each'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in`each_strongly_connected_component_from'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in`each'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
>       from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in`tsort_each'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in`initialize!'
>       from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in`require_environment!'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:142:in `require_application_and_environment!'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:67:in`console'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
>       from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in`'
>       from /app/bin/rails:4:in `require'
>       from /app/bin/rails:4:in`'
>     yesijiedeMacBook-Pro:blog killernova$

**:qiqiu** is another gem "carrierwave-qiniu".

**Everything is ok** in localhost:3000, so anyone would like to tell me where am I wrong? Thanks!

github: https://github.com/killernova/blog

Comment: please post your PictureUploader file

Comment: @Amit Sharma I'v added the file above, thanks.

Comment: Do you have `require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'` in `config/environment.rb` file? If not try adding it and check.

Comment: Please post your Article schema file, also please confirm your article model has `picture` attribute.
put following lines in your `picture_uploader.rb` file.
`require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'
require 'carrierwave/processing/mime_types'` and try to run the code

Comment: there is no need to execute `heroku run rails s` command on heroku because when you upload code on heroku it automatically starts the server. just do one thing `heroku restart` so that your app instance will get restarted.

Comment: what exact path to `uploaders/picture_uploader.rb`? is it within `app`? looks like the class is not loaded before rails initializes it's models, so it can't find the class-name.

Comment: @phoet the path is app/uploaders/picture_uploader.rb, if the class is not loaded before rails initialises it's models, why does it work well in localhost?

Comment: @Amit Sharma I run `heroku run rails s` is just to see where goes wrong, and the error is also present in _heroku logs_. The strange thing is I found I can't run `heroku run rails c` today cause the same error was listed.

Comment: @Pavan I've tried and seems no help.

Comment: @AmitSharma I've done what you told and unlucky it also failed.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. I want to say that maybe the core issue is why the app can run in localhost but failed in remote? The ways you told maybe  are the solutions to the problem which app can't run in development ENV, so let's try to focus our attentions on production environment. Thanks again!

Comment: @killernova can you try using `::PictureUploader` in `mount_uploader` or use a string instead of a class?

Comment: @phoet the README.md of carrierwave tells us that using class is correct...

Comment: @killernova this is just to check if the class is actually loaded in the application. the answer that danzcreation gave makes sense in this regard.

Comment: @phoet I tried, but nothing changed, thanks.

Comment: I added my github of demo so maybe someone would like to check the code。

Comment: Thanks everyone, problem was solved by adding the missing files. Love you~~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you commit your `app/uploaders/` to heroku master?

I have same error, was forget to add those uploader files to remote repository

Comment: If I want to add app/uploaders/ to remote, I should run `heroku run rails g uploader Picture`, unfortunately it will lead to the same error.

Comment: OK, I found the problem as what you said. The files was missing in remote, cause when I pushed files to remote I got a warning that files were not tracked. I added these files and pushed again, it's ok now. But why did git untrack these files? Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: @killernova git did not untrack those files, you forgot to add them to git in the first place.